How can I solve a cookie /crumb request from Yahoo finance?
I'm trying to download Yahoo finance historical quotes.
After some requests, Yahoo start to answer without quotes, but with an error string.
I've read the Yahoo request a cookie and crumb mechanism I didn't understand.
This is my C# code.
How can I add the cookie and crumb request?
async Task DownloadQuoteFromYahoo(string symbol)
{
    // Set symbol and date range for historical data
    DateTime startDate = dtpUpdateFromDate.Value;
    DateTime endDate = dtpUpdateToDate.Value;

    string interval = "1d"; // Intervals: "1m", "2m", "5m", "15m",
                            // "30m", "60m", "90m", "1h", "1d",
                            // "5d", "1wk", "1mo", or "3mo"

    // Set URL for API request
    string url = string.Format("https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{0}?period1={1}&period2={2}&interval={3}&events=history",
        symbol, (int)(startDate.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds, (int)(endDate.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds, interval);

    // Create HttpClient with custom user-agent
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0");

    // Read response data
    var responseData = await GetWebContentAsync(url);

    // ...

}


The bounty attracted a ChatGPT (or similar) plagiariser.

Can you please share a typical usage scenario that gets you to an error? I built a crumb-finding function, but I can't seem to get in the situation when it is actually needed so I can verify its usefulness, see dotNet fiddle.

cont' - Now deleted.

Here are my crumb and cookie detection functions (RevalidateCrumbAsync and RevalidateCookiesAsync in the code below);
I get the crumb from htps://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{symbol} with a given
or default symbol and the cookie from https://login.yahoo.com/.
The main issue (as I said in the message) is that it isn't battle-tested,
since I haven't got yet into a case where I don't  get the full csv data,
even without using the crumb or cookie. There are probably some adjustments/improvements necessary when I get to actually fight against an unresponsive server.
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net.Http;

var requests = new QuoteRequest[]
{
    new QuoteRequest(
        "GOOG",
        new DateTime(2004, 1, 1),
        new DateTime(2019, 12, 31),
        "1d"),
    new QuoteRequest(
        "MSFT",
        new DateTime(2004, 1, 1),
        new DateTime(2019, 12, 31),
        "1d"),
    new QuoteRequest(
        "INTC",
        new DateTime(2004, 1, 1),
        new DateTime(2019, 12, 31),
        "1d"),
    new QuoteRequest(
        "AMZN",
        new DateTime(2004, 12, 1),
        new DateTime(2019, 12, 31),
        "1d"),
    new QuoteRequest(
        "IBM",
        new DateTime(2004, 12, 1),
        new DateTime(2019, 12, 31),
        "1d")
};

var cookie = "";
var crumb = await RevalidateCrumbAsync();
cookie = await RevalidateCookiesAsync();
//Console.WriteLine($"crumb = '{crumb}'");
//Console.WriteLine($"cookie = '{cookie}'");

foreach(var req in requests)
{
    Console.WriteLine(req);
    var csv = await DownloadQuoteFromYahooAsync(req.symbol, req.from, req.to, req.interval, crumb);
    Console.WriteLine($"{csv.Length} bytes");
    Console.WriteLine();
}

return;

HttpClient newConfiguredHttpClient(bool useCookie = false)
{
    var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("User-Agent",
        "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:75.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/75.0");
    if (useCookie && cookie.Length > 0)
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Cookie", cookie);
    }
    httpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);

    return httpClient;
}

async Task<string> RevalidateCrumbAsync(string symbol = "GOOG")
{
    var url = $"https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/{symbol}";
    HttpClient httpClient = newConfiguredHttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);

    var html = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

    var pos = html.IndexOf("\"crumb\":\"");
    if (pos <= 0) return "";
    var pos1 = html.IndexOf(":\"", pos) + 2;
    var pos2 = html.IndexOf('"', pos1);
    if (pos2 <= 0) return "";

    return html.Substring(pos1, pos2 - pos1);
}

async Task<string> RevalidateCookiesAsync()
{
    var url = "https://login.yahoo.com/";
    HttpClient httpClient = newConfiguredHttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url);
    foreach (var header in response.Headers)
    {
        if (header.Key != "Set-Cookie") continue;
        var cookies = "";
        foreach (var cookie in header.Value)
        {
            if(cookies.Length > 0)
            {
                cookies += "; ";
            }
            var pos = cookie.IndexOf(";");
            if(pos > 0)
            {
                cookies += cookie.Substring(0, pos);
            }
            else
            {
                cookies += cookie;
            }
        }
        return cookies;
    }
    return "";
}


async Task<string> DownloadQuoteFromYahooAsync(string symbol, DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, string interval, string crumb = "")
{
    // Set URL for API request
    var period1 = (int)(startDate.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds);
    var period2 = (int)(endDate.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalSeconds);
    var url = $"https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{symbol}?period1={period1}&period2={period2}&interval={interval}&events=history";
    if (crumb.Length > 0)
    {
        url += "&crumb=" + crumb;
    }
    Console.WriteLine(url);

    HttpClient httpClient = newConfiguredHttpClient(true);
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(url).ConfigureAwait(false);

    Console.WriteLine($"status = {response.StatusCode}");
    //Console.WriteLine($"headers = {response.Headers}");
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
}

internal record QuoteRequest(string symbol, DateTime from, DateTime to, string interval);

dotNet fiddle
